# Make data table header in vuetify width of rows readjust by dragging the margins of the rows left or right?

Tags: vue.js, web, vuetify.js, styling

A colorful example of that is excel application. In it you can adjust the width and the height of cells to your liking simply by dragging the margins of the cells. I was wondering if it's possible in vuetify.

Comment: See this feature request - [Resizable datatable column widths](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3278). This is not possible with Vuetify and probably never will be. Your only option is to implement it yourself using `headers` slot which will be a lot of work (need to re-implement lots of Vuetify build-in functionality in headers)...

Comment: I'm gonna switch to ag-Grid. It is a much more powerful tool for grids. Thank for your reply!